# What are some good questions for this trick, if $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}=\frac{e}{f}=\dots=\alpha$ then $\alpha=\frac{a+c+e+...}{b+d+f+...}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, big-list

I need some good algebra questions that are applications of this trick, often in a non obvious and elegant way:   $$\text{If } \frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}=\frac{e}{f}=\dots=\alpha \text{ then } \alpha=\frac{a+c+e+...}{b+d+f+...}$$

Comment: Do you happen to have a copy of Higher Algebra by Hall and Knight? It contains quite a few of these in the first chapter.

Comment: @ParthKohli Unfortunately no. Can you give some examples? :)

Comment: @125a8owp, https://archive.org/details/higheralgebraseq00hall and also https://archive.org/details/higheralgebra032813mbp

Comment: Does anyone happen to know the name of this property of ratios?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. If $\displaystyle\frac a{b+c}=\frac b{c+a}=\frac c{a+b};$  prove that each ratio $\displaystyle=\frac12$ if $\displaystyle a+b+c\ne0$
2. If  $\displaystyle\frac{a-b}{x^2}=\frac{b-c}{y^2}=\frac{c-a}{z^2}$ prove that $\displaystyle a=b=c$
3. If  $\displaystyle\frac{a-b}{a^2+ab+b^2}=\frac{b-c}{b^2+bc+c^2}=\frac{c-a}{c^2+ca+a^2}$ prove that $\displaystyle a=b=c$ (for a special condition)
4. If  $\displaystyle\frac{a+b}{a^2+ab+b^2}=\frac{b+c}{b^2+bc+c^2}$ and $a\ne b\ne c$ prove that each ratio $=\displaystyle\frac{c+a}{c^2+ca+a^2}$

Comment: Did you read my question?

Comment: @125a8owp, Edited

Comment: That's better :)

Comment: @125a8owp, Two more. Try the last one

Comment: Oh nice! Thanks.

Comment: @125a8owp, I used apply it in Trigonometry, too like : If $\displaystyle\tan x=\frac ab,\frac{\sin x}a=\frac{\cos x}b$   $\implies\frac{\sin^2x}{a^2}=\frac{\cos^2x}{b^2}=\frac{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}{a^2+b^2}\implies \cos^2x=\cdots$ etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16149/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-125a8owp).

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$\begin{align}
\color{#c00000}{\large\alpha}&={a \over b}=\color{#c00000}{\large{c \over d}}\ \imp\ {a \over c}={b \over d}\ \imp\ {a \over c} + 1 ={b \over d} + 1\
\imp\ {a + c \over c}={b + d \over d}\ \imp\
{a + c \over b + d} = \color{#c00000}{\large{c \over d}} 
\end{align}

> $$
> \mbox{Then,}\quad  {a + c \over b + d} = \alpha
> $$

Now, we have
$$
{a + c \over b + d}={e \over f}=\cdots=\alpha
$$

> We can repeat the above procedure as needed. The general result will follow.

Comment: @125a8owp I'm sorry I wrote a proof. I didn't know it was not important. Thanks.